# Seeing form data with Node.js script

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, forms

I'm a beginner at web development, so maybe I'm mixing up some of the things. I'm stuck at this "stage".

Basically, I'm learning HTML, particularly Forms.
I want to test whether the forms are sending data correctly.

In a book for learning HTML there're instructions to check this with a Node.js (Javasript) script.
So basically, I'm supposed to create a js file with the following code:

```
var http = require('http');
var querystring = require('querystring');
http.createServer(function (req, res) {
 switch(req.url) {
 case '/form':
 if (req.method == 'POST') {
 console.log("[200] " + req.method + " to " + req.url);
 var fullBody = '';
 req.on('data', function(chunk) {
 fullBody += chunk.toString();
 });
 req.on('end', function() {
 res.writeHead(200, "OK", {'Content-Type': 'text/html'});
 res.write('<html><head><title>Post data</title></head><body>');
 res.write('<style>th, td {text-align:left; padding:5px; color:black}\n');
 res.write('th {background-color:grey; color:white; min-width:10em}\n');
 res.write('td {background-color:lightgrey}\n');
 res.write('caption {font-weight:bold}</style>');
 res.write('<table border="1"><caption>Form Data</caption>');
 res.write('<tr><th>Name</th><th>Value</th>');
 var dBody = querystring.parse(fullBody);
 for (var prop in dBody) {
 res.write("<tr><td>" + prop + "</td><td>" + dBody[prop] + "</td></tr>");
 }
 res.write('</table></body></html>');
 res.end();
 });
 } else {
 console.log("[405] " + req.method + " to " + req.url);
 res.writeHead(405, "Method not supported", {'Content-Type': 'text/html'});
 res.end('<html><head><title>405 - Method not supported</title></head><body>' +
 '<h1>Method not supported.</h1></body></html>');
 }
 break;
 default:
 res.writeHead(404, "Not found", {'Content-Type': 'text/html'});
 res.end('<html><head><title>404 - Not found</title></head><body>' +
 '<h1>Not found.</h1></body></html>');
 console.log("[404] " + req.method + " to " + req.url);
 };
}).listen(8080);
```

Then I'm supposed to run the file with Node.js, and when I enter some data in a form and press the "Submit" button in a page created on a local HTML file, I should be redirected to a page with a table that shows the data entered. The url to which I'm redirected should end with ":8080/form".

I suppose I should set up a local web server simulation? I fail to set up everything by myself (too many things for me to learn at once), as the writer of the book doesn't explain quite everything in detail.

What exactly should I do here? Change the value in the **action** attribute in the form element to what exactly? Should I also set a specific any particular **href** value in the base element in the HTML file? I understand the js file should be in the same folder as the html file.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

What you need is a web server to serve the form and accept a POST from that form.

NodeJS (a JavaScript runtime) and Express (Web Server) is one option. There's also PHP + Apache, or PHP + Nginx, etc.

To stick with the recommendation, install [NodeJS](https://nodejs.org/en/) and [Express](https://expressjs.com/).

Here is a [guide](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Server-side/Express_Nodejs).

Comment: I don't quite understand everything. I installed Node.js (not sure why I need Express also), I made a server.js file in the desired folder, I ran the file in Node.js, and now I can open http://localhost:8080/ in my browser. I can also open the html file (with the form) with http://localhost:8080/html_file_name.html, which is located in the same folder as the server.js file. It seems like I can't run two js files at once on Node, so I can't run the form file. What exactly do I do here to get the desired result?